# Delphi, Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Extended'

Tags: delphi, типы

Впал в ступор.
Накидал функцию получения факториала.

```
function factorial(n: string): string;
var i: integer;
k,l:real;
begin

  k:= strtofloat(n);
  if k = 0 then
    begin
      l:= 1;
    end
  else
    begin
      l:=1;
      for i:=1 to int(k) do l:= l*i;
    end;
  result:= floattostr(l);
end;
```

При попытке компиляции отдается ошибка, о которой написано в заголовке вопроса, хотя для возвращения все приведено в нужный тип данных. 
Конкретно ругается на строку с циклом.

Пробовал менять тип переменной **l** на integer, реакция та же.

Чем может быть вызвана данная проблема, помимо криворукости?

Comment: так вы посмотрите в F1 на то, что возвращает int, и сразу все станет ясно. Вам нужно Round или Trunc. Даже лень писать ответ, если честно...

Comment: @Виталий RS  У вас переменная result  не определена. Кроме того функция ничего не возвращает.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Result и не нужно определять (вернее, объявлять). Это и есть результат функции, который она возвращает. Переменная Result присутствует в любой функции всегда, так же как и Self присутствует в любом объекте.

Comment: @kami А result не чувствительна к регистру?

Comment: @VladfromMoskow Pascal и его наследник Delphi никогда не были чувствительны к регистрам переменных и методов.

Comment: в дополнение отмечу, что с такой реализацией факториала вы достаточно быстро выйдете за границы `integer` и `real`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас ошибка в преобразовании переменной `k` в целое. Вот как объявлена функция `Int`:

```
function Int(const X: Extended): Extended;
```

А вот, как она описывается:

> Функция `Int` возвращает целочисленную часть числа с плавающей точкой,
>   как число с плавающей точкой.

Очевидно, что эта функция не подходит для того, чтобы преобразовать `Real` в `Integer` (а цикл `for` работает именно с `Integer`). Для такого преобразования вам надо использовать либо функцию `Trunc` (которая делает то же самое, что и `Int`, только результатом будет `Integer`), либо `Round`, которая округляет число до целого.

```
function Trunc (const Number : Extended): Integer;
function Round (const Number : Extended): Int64;
```

Примеры:

```
begin
  ShowMessage('Round(12.75) = ' + IntToStr(Round(12.75)));
  ShowMessage('Trunc(12.75) = ' + IntToStr(Trunc(12.75)));
  ShowMessage('  Int(12.75) = ' + FloatToStr(Int(12.75)));
  ShowMessage(' Frac(12.75) = ' + FloatToStr(Frac(12.75)));
end;
```

Выведет:

```
Round(12.75) = 13
Trunc(12.75) = 12
Int(12.75) = 12
Frac(12.75) = 0.75
```

P.S. Судя по тому, что вы пытались изменить тип переменной `l`, вы неправильно поняли к чему конкретно относится сообщение об ошибке. А это произошло от того, что вы написали в одну строку и условие цикла и его тело. Стоит придерживаться нормального форматирования кода, особенно на начальных парах:

```
for I := 1 to Trunc(K) do begin
  L := L * I;
end
```

Comment: по поводу нормального форматирования - тогда begin тоже нужно выносить на отдельную строку, иначе получается то, что обычно называют `egypt-style`

Comment: @kami где конкретно написан begin не суть важно и дело вкуса. Я привык экономить одну строчку и писать его в ряд. Но вот код, нужно разносить по разным строкам.

Answer (score 4):

Факториал числа n (обозначается n!) — произведение всех натуральных чисел до n включительно: По определению полагают 0! = 1. Факториал определён только для целых неотрицательных чисел.
Правильнее конечно передавать в функцию целое положительное число, но не знаю всех подробностей использования функции, поэтому код приблизительно должен быть таким:

```
function factorial(const n: string): string;
var 
  i: Integer;
  k, l: Integer;
begin      
  if not TryStrToInt(n, k) then begin
    ShowMessage('Введите целое положительное число для вычисления факториала.');
    Result := '';
    Exit;
  end;         

  if k < 0 then
     k := -k;
  l := 1;
  if k > 0 then begin
    for i := 1 to k do
      l := l * i;
  end;
  Result := IntToStr(l);
end;
```